# Pandas - Select rows based on a hierachy of conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where I would like to obtain the *'first available'* index based on a nested hierarchy of values in some of the data frame's columns.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

foo = ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b']
bar = [0,0,1,1,2,2,1,1]
foobar = ['x',1,1,2,2,3,4,5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':foo,'bar':bar,'foobar':foobar})
```

which gives you:

```
  foo  bar foobar
0   a    0      x
1   a    0      1
2   a    1      1
3   a    1      2
4   b    2      2
5   b    2      3
6   b    1      4
7   b    1      5
```

The rules should be the following: For each value in `foo` choose one and only one row index based on values in `bar` and `foobar`. For `bar`, this is the hierarchy of conditions: `0 > 1 > 2 > ...` and for `foobar` it's `'x' > 1 > 2 > ...`

`foobar` should be nested in `bar` so if there are multiple available values for `bar` only consider rows for the *'first available'* value in `bar` and only then obtain one row index based on the hierarchy of values in `foobar` for that specific value of `bar`.

Expected output:

For my example, the indices `0` and `6` should be chosen.

Comment: What determines  the hierarchy?

Comment: This should be determined by the user.

Comment: How will what's determined by the user reach pandas and in what state? Is it just the order of `bar` and `foobar` in the `df`?

Comment: Yes. There could be more columns than just `bar` and `foobar` in the data frame. The user should be able to determine a hierarchy of hierarchies so to say. One could roughly imagine it as `bar > foobar`. Furthermore there's a hierarchy of `0 > 1 > 2 > ...` for the values of `bar` and hierarchy of  `'x' > 1 > 2 > ...` for the values of `foobar`. Maybe one approach would be to convert the columns of interest into categorical variables. Then one could set up a user-defined hierarchy of factor levels for all values of `bar` and all values of `foobar`?

Comment: Will it always be the first one in `foo` group? Your expected output is 0 and 4. Could you show a case where it's not the first one?

Comment: No it's not necessarily always the first row for every `foo` group. I will update my question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'], key=lambda x: x.replace('x', 0).astype(int))
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['foo'])
res = df[~mask].index
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
Int64Index([0, 4], dtype='int64')
```

The idea is to sort the rows of the DataFrame by *hierarchy* priority, replacing 'x' for 0 (or any other high priority). Then find the rows that are duplicated by the *foo* column.

**UPDATE**

For the new case you could do:

```
df = df.set_index('foo').sort_index().sort_values(by=['bar', 'foobar'],
                                                  key=lambda x: x.replace('x', 0).astype(int)).reset_index()
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['foo'])
res = df[~mask].index
print(res)
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'` when I use your code

Comment: @JohannesWiesner What pandas version are you using?

Comment: My pandas version is '1.0.5'

Comment: The key parameter was added in 1.1.0

Comment: Sorry, I had to update my question and change the values in `foo`. I just discovered that your approach only works when `foo` only contains integers. In my real data frame `foo`  holds participant ids which are unique strings (e.g. `'sub_a123'`).

Comment: What are the other columns going to be? Also strings or numbers?

Comment: For the other columns, it's fine as it is. In my real data frame `bar` represents timepoints of MRI acquisition sessions as integers and `foobar` represents run numbers of MRI scans (where `x` in reality stands for `no_run_numbers`)

Comment: Do you think there could also be a solution where one 1.) does not have to manipulate the data frame itself and 2.) where the data frame does not have an ascending list of indexes (e.g. there are gaps in the indices, like `1,2,4`?